# How to display a different message in first input and another message in second input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def player_choice():

marker = ' '
while marker not in ['X','O']:
    
    marker = input('What do you want X or O? ')
       
if marker == 'X':
    return ('X','O')
else:
    return ('O','X')
```

I want to make it so that when the user inputs any integer the very first time it displays "Please select from X and O" and when the user enters the wrong value the second time it displays "Do you want to play the game seriously?", along with the loop.

Comment: The code you posted does not make sense because it is not indented according to Python's rules. Perhaps you would like to [edit] your question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you would probably just need to add a counter and another test to your "if/else" block such as in the following code snippet.

```
def player_choice():
    tries = 0
    marker = ' '
    while marker not in ['X','O']:
        marker = input('What do you want X or O? ')
       
        if marker == 'X':
            return ('X','O')
        elif marker == 'O':
            return ('O','X')
        else:
            tries += 1
            if tries > 1:
                print("Please be serious")
                tries = 0
            
choices = player_choice()

print("Choices are:", choices)
```

Testing that out, this is what I saw on my terminal.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/PlayerCoice$ python3 Choice.py 
What do you want X or O? Q
What do you want X or O? Q
Please be serious
What do you want X or O? O
Choices are: ('O', 'X')
```

You can give that a try.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. 
Could you please share how would you come to this logic???